# Git push to drupal.org always returns "Everything up-to-date"

Tags: version-control

This same question was asked many times, but for now I didn't find any help in the responses.

I have a project in a [sandbox](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/cfreed/2469725) which I frequently pushed to the DrupalGit [repository](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-cFreed-2469725/tree/) without any issue during review process.

Then after successfully getting [permission](https://www.drupal.org/node/2471871#comment-9925362), I first wanted to simply promote my sandbox to a full project according to [these instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1068952), but for some reason editing my sandbox page never showed me the "Promote" tab.

So I decided to create a [full project](https://www.drupal.org/project/multilang) from scratch, then I followed its "Version control" tab documentation to create and populate the corresponding [repository](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/multilang/tree/): compared to the sandbox's one, you can see that it only contains the `myModule.info` file.
(this file is not the "true" myModule's info file: it was created in the earlier steps prescribed by the above doc).

Once successfully pushed this and added a "7.x-1.0" tag as also prescribed, I locally copied all my real files from sandbox to full-project directory, `git-add`ed them and `git-commit`ted them.

Then from now on, any `git push origin 7.x-1.0` simply returns "Everything up-to-date", and obviously nothing is updated in the DrupalGit repository.

I looked at many posts and docs, in the Drupal community and elsewhere, tried a lot of more or less serious methods.
I even dropped all files but `myModule.info` from my local repository: pushing this committed situation also returns "Everything up-to-date", and indeed the same after bringing them again.

I could observed something weird when clicking the `myModule.info` file to display its contents:

- in the [sandbox repository](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-cFreed-2469725/tree/) it appears formatted with line numbers, as expected, and clicking "plain" displays its raw content
- but in the [full project repository](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/multilang/tree/) it displays in hexdump mode, And clicking "plain" causes its download to be proposed!

This clearly means that the file in a somewhat strange state, and midht be significative... but not for me at the moment :-)

Comment: `git push origin 7.x-1.0` pushes you 7.x-1.0 tag. Try `git push origin 7.x-1.x`

Comment: @ya.teck. Yes, it was the same with this `git push origin 7.x-1.x`, as well as with many other tries like adding `-u` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This not a real "answer" to the question I asked, but only the method I finally found to get out of my blocking situation.

Since it seemed not possible to make the remote repository to accept push attempts from its associated local repository, I took the problem from the opposite end.

After all it appears as a quite simple solution:

1. I renamed my local repository, say to `myModule.old`
2. I cloned the remote repository with
   `git clone --branch 7.x-1.x [myName]@git.drupal.org:project/myModule.git`,
   so getting a new `myModule` local repository
3. then I pasted whole contents from `myModule.old` into `myModule`, added and committed them
4. and finally used a simple `git push origin` (NOTE: without tag mentioned), with success

BTW, it's interesting to notice that trying with the tag mention again returned the "Everything up-to-date" message.
In the other hand, once pushed new contents, the `myModule.info` file displays normally rather than with the previous weird fashion.

Hope this helps somebody.